# DistanceMatrixApi old release has dependency on licence key?

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I am using Google Maps API **enterprise key** for authentication with **Google Maps web services**.
Upgraded google-maps-services.jar from v0.1.17 to v0.1.18 in the project and got authentication error.

```
DistanceMatrixApiRequest request = DistanceMatrixApi.getDistanceMatrix(context, orgs, dests);
// using google-maps-services-0.1.17.jar below line works fine.
DistanceMatrix matrix = request.await(); // google-maps-services-0.1.18.jar returns Server Error: 403 Forbidden
```

Rolling back jar solves the error. What could be a reason for such bazar API error code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in v0.1.18 [GeoApiContext throwing 403 Forbidden with enterprise credentials](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/248)

Using v0.1.19 solved the issue.